# Krull dimension of finite rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, krull-dimension

I have the following question(s):

Can the Krull dimension of a finite ring be any natural number?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270982/proof-that-prime-ideals-of-finite-ring-are-maximal

Comment: The suggested duplicate certainly answers the question, although the questions are entirely different...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any finite ring is Artinian, and hence has Krull dimension zero. The reason is, that in any Artinian ring every prime ideal is maximal.

References: Theorem 8.5 of Atiyah MacDonald.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @LSt you are welcome!